# Time bound function to rotate tokens

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a python function that requires temporary credentials to be rotated every N minutes.
Here is how the implementation looks like:

```
if valid_bucket(bucket_name):
    try:
        aws_token = get_token(account_id=account_id, region="us-east-1")
        s3 = get_boto_client_with_creds('s3', aws_token=aws_token)
        print("this is s3 object", s3)
    except Exception as e:
        print("error ", e)
    bucket_parse_function(s3)
```

My use-case is to call the `aws_token` variable if `bucket_parse_function()` has already run for N minutes.
Can anyone help me change the implementation in such a way that I am able to achieve the goal of refreshing token every N minutes of execution of `bucket_parse_function()`.

Comment: So you need to call `bucket_parse_function()` for every `N` minutes and with a new set of temporary credentials...is my understanding right?...

Comment: If the `bucket_parse_function()` has run for N minutes, we need to call the `aws_token` variable again which will generate the new set of tokens required for the function.

Comment: It sounds like `bucket_parse_function` should be calling `get_token` and `get_boto_client_with_creds` internally as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to save the time at which you acquired the token last and then each time you run this check if the token has expired.

So something like

```
if valid_bucket(bucket_name):
    if token_acquired_time is None or time.time() - TOKEN_EXPIRATION_SECONDS > token_acquired_time:
        try:
            aws_token = get_token(account_id=account_id, region="us-east-1")
            s3 = get_boto_client_with_creds('s3', aws_token=aws_token)
            token_acquired_time = time.time()
            print("this is s3 object", s3)
       except Exception as e:
            print("error ", e)
     bucket_parse_function(s3)
```

And before all this you need to set

```
token_acquired_time = None 
TOKEN_EXPIRATION_SECONDS = 60 * N  # convert N minutes to seconds
```

somewhere where it will only run once.

Note this won't refresh the token every N minutes, but it will refresh the token the next time you attempt to use it if it is after the N minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS STS `AssumeRole API` here.

**From AWS docs**

To assume a role, an application calls the AWS STS AssumeRole API operation and passes the ARN of the role to use. The operation creates a new session with temporary credentials. This session has the same permissions as the identity-based policies for that role.

May be you can do something like this:

```
import boto3
import time

# Assuming you do this with your IAM user credentials initially
bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
def valid_bucket(bucket_name):
  s3 = boto3.client('s3')
  try:
    s3.client.head_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
    print("Bucket Exists!")
    return True
  except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    return False

def temp_credentials(bucket_name):
  if valid_bucket(bucket_name):
    try:
       sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
       assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
                           RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::account-of-role-to-assume:role/name-of-role",
                           RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
                                                 )
       # From the response that contains the assumed role, get the temporary 
       # credentials that can be used to make subsequent API calls
       credentials=assumed_role_object['Credentials']
       # now acess your bucket with temporary credentials.
       # Use the temporary credentials that AssumeRole returns to make a 
       # connection to Amazon S3  
    except Exception as e:
    print("error ", e)
  return credentials
  
# get credentials here and call parse_bucket_function() for the first time
check=True
while check:
   credentials = temp_credentials()
   # create client object here
   s3_obj=boto3.client(
                       's3',
                       aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
                       aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
                       aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
                      )
   start = time.time()
   bucket_parse_function(s3_obj)
   elapsed = time.time()-start
   # convert N into a readable format in minutes.
   if elapsed != N:
     check=False
     break
   else:
     continue:
```

By default, your role session lasts for one hour. You can specify the value for the **DurationSeconds** parameter.

**Reference:** [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html)